# Magento Importing categories from 1.8 to 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, import

We are trying to **export/import** categories from Magento 1.8 to 1.9.

We are facing the below error while importing categories:

```
Path provided is not a valid one.
```

Find the screenshot below:

[image]

We have uploaded the category csv file under **var/import/category**

Thanks....!

Answer (score 1):

Download this code and install it.
https://blog.surgeryxchange.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/import_categories.zip

> **Note** Before install
>
> Disable `Compilation` in `system>tools>Compilation`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is this for magento 1.9?

Comment: for me working.

Comment: Thanks, but categories are imported with different category ids,

Comment: When i imported the products products are not assigned to categories.